# 'Not defined' when using subroutine

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to call the "name" under 'create():' in 'show():', but it says it's not defined. How can I save my input in 'create():', so I can use it in the other subroutines (in 'show():' for this example).

Thank you

I have tried to ask the user input after the choice part, but it doesn't solve it. I keep getting the same error.

```
import sys

class data:
    name = ""
    average = ""


def menu():
    print("1) Data input")
    print("2) Print data")
    print("3) Give file name")
    print("4) Save")
    print("5) Read file")
    print("0) Stop")
    choice = int(input("Give your choice: "))
    print()
    return choice


def save(datalist, namea):
    f = open(namea, "w")
    for data in datalist:
        row = str("{};{}").format(data.name, data.average)
        f.write(row)
        f.write("\n")
    f.close()

def read(datalist, namea):
    f = open(namea, "r")
    for row in f:
        row = row.split(";")
        dataa = data()
        dataa.name = str(row[0])
        dataa.average = float(row[1])
        datalist.append(dataa)
    return datalist



def printt(datalist):
    for data in datalist:
        print(data.name, data.average)

def name():
    namea = str(input("Give a name: "))
    return namea

def inputt(datalist):
    dataa = data()
    dataa.name = str(input("Give a name: "))
    dataa.average = float(input("Give the average (float): "))
    datalist.append(dataa)
    print()
    return(datalist)


def main():
    try:
        datalist = []
        while True:
            choice = menu()
            if (choice == 1):
                datalist = inputt(datalist)

            elif (choice == 2):
                printt(datalist)

            elif (choice == 3):
                namea = name()

            elif (choice == 4):
                save(datalist, namea)

            elif (choice == 5):
                datalist = read(datalist, namea)

            elif (choice == 0):
                print("The program was closed {} at {}".format(datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%d.%m.%Y'), datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M:%S')))
                return False
    except Exception:
        sys.exit(0)


main()
```

I excpect it to print the name I input in 1), when I call 2).
For example: 
*choice 1)*
1) Give name: Daniel
*choice 2)*
2) Prints: Hello Daniel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you got a problem with your Scope.

The *name* variable is only local.
See https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/global-local-nonlocal-variables for more Information.

a hotfix would be using global-variables instead, or as Aaron D. Rodriguez suggested passing the name as parameter to the show-function.

```
def lista():
    print("1) Write name.")
    print("2) Print written name.")
    print("0) Stop.")
    choice = int(input("Give your choice: "))
    return choice 

def create():
    global name
    name = input("Give name: ")
    return(name)

def show():
    global name
    print(name)
    return


def main():
    print("Choose from the following list:")
    while True:
        choice = lista()
        if (choice == 0):
           print("Thanks for using the program!")
           break
        elif (choice == 1):
            create()

        elif (choice == 2):
            show()

        else:
            print("Input not detected.\nStopping.")
            break
main()
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I got told to try to avoid the global-variables, as it can bring some confusion when working in groups. Is there another way around?

Comment: avoiding globals is a good thing to do. i thought you were searching for an ugly hotfix. if you wanna do it clean, you should stick to Aaron D. Rodriguez solution

Answer (score 1):

You would have to have show() include a parameter in it. For example:

```
def show(n):
    print(n)
```

So that when you call show(n), it prints whatever you include as n.

So if you called show(name). It would print out name.

```
def show(n):
    print(n)

show(name) #This would print out name.
```

You also don't need *return* unless you are returning a value. Return doesn't make the code go back, it just makes the function return a value. So you do need return for list() and create(), but not for show(n).

**Edit**
You also would want to set the user input as a variable when you call create.

```
def main():
    print("Choose from the following list:")
    while True:
        choice = lista()
        if (choice == 0):
           print("Thanks for using the program!")
           break
        elif (choice == 1):
            name = create() #Here is where you should change it

        elif (choice == 2):
            show(name)

        else:
            print("Input not detected.\nStopping.")
            break
```

Comment: If I change show(): to: `def show(n):
    print(n)

show(name)` It says the error; TypeError: show() missing 1 required positional argument: 'n'

Comment: I made an edit towards the bottom, check if that fixes it.

Comment: Hi!
Sorry for not replying for you earlier. Your edited solution didn't work out unfortunately, so I was thinking on how to do it. I created a list where the written data goes to. I updated the OP with my solution. 
Thanks for helping me!